# What would be the proactive steps that we need to take when salesforce disables SSL and enables TLS?

Tags: api, integration, callout, ssl, tls

I heard that salesforce would stop the support for SSL 3.0 and will enforce TLS 1.0 and higher.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-disabling-SSL-3-0-encryption

From salesforce, we are making callouts to SAP system and get data from there. What changes should I make to SFDC side as well as on SAP side?  Also, what suggestions should I give to tech guys who are on SAP side?

Experts please clarify it is very urgent for us so that we are in a position to tell our client. Experts, any thoughts on this? Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Is this in regard to the recent SSL3.0 POODLE attack vulnerability?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I have referred this article and getting confused as it explains the solution in a single sentence like this, "....... If a customer uses call-out integrations, then they need to ensure TLS 1.0 encryption or greater is enabled in the integration. " I literally do not understand what we need to do on either end i.e., SFDC side and SAP side. I am making callout from SFDC to SAP and get data from there.

Comment: Which article are you referring to?

Comment: I am sorry . forgot to include the article, please see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-disabling-SSL-3-0-encryption&language=en_US

Comment: You could try disabling SSL in whatever system you use to connect to SF and verify that the connection uses TLS.

Comment: @Snowman - can you please explain how can we verify that?

Comment: @Mehul I have not done this myself in every program, but I do know it is possible in various web browsers. In IE settings, for example, there is a list of protocols and you can check and uncheck different ones. If you are using a Java program, you can tell whatever is connecting what protocols and encryption algorithms you want to allow. If you are using a third-party tool, you will need to look at the documentation for that tool.

Answer (score 1):

All Salesforce sandboxes now have this implemented. Point one of your sandboxes to a test instance of SAP and run your integration test scripts.